# Spreadsheetlight save as working too slow

Tags: c#, winforms, spreadsheetlight

I am working on a winform with spreadsheetlight library.I want to create a excel file with specific name under a specific folder when user clicked on "Save to Excel" button. Ihave tried the below code so far.

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

sl.SaveAs(path + "\\" + dosyaismi + ".xlsx");
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path + "\\" + dosyaismi + ".xlsx");
if (fi.Exists)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@path + "\\" + dosyaismi + ".xlsx");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dosya bulunamadı!");
}
```

When program run and clicked that button first time it takes 2 minutes to create file.But without closing program I clicked that button again with different filename it creates file immediately.

I searched for 2 hours but ı didn't find any solution.Can anyone help what is the problem?

Comment: Is Excel running the second time? `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` starts Excel, which takes a while to load the first time you run it. The saving may not be the bottleneck it may be launching Excel.

Comment: I debugged code , actually the "sl.saveAs..." line works slow.Other parts work with normal speed

Comment: i have the same problem, it seems that when i removed the hyperlinks from worksheet the sl.SaveAs works @8 times faster